# Flutter: Stripe payment passes to success without having to display the stripe bottom sheet

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

Stripe payment passes to success without having to display the bottom sheet to the user to enter the bank account number and other info

The code below should allow me to display the bottom sheet but the bottom sheet does not appear.

````
 Future<void> initPaymentSheet(BuildContext contextsec,
     {required String email, required String amount}) async {
   try {

     // 1. create payment intent on the server
     final response = await http.post(
         Uri.parse('https://stripep'),
         body: {
           'email': "abibou@gmail.com",//email,
           'amount': amount.toString(),
         });

     final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body); 
     //2. initialize the payment sheet
     await stripe.Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
       paymentSheetParameters: stripe.SetupPaymentSheetParameters(           
         customFlow: true, 
        paymentIntentClientSecret: jsonResponse['paymentIntent'],
         merchantDisplayName: 'NAme',
         customerId: jsonResponse['customer'],
         customerEphemeralKeySecret: jsonResponse['ephemeralKey'],
         style: ThemeMode.dark,
       ),
     );
     // 3. confirm payment on the server
     final responseConfirm = await http.post(
         Uri.parse(
             'https://stripecon'),
         body: {
           'intentId': jsonResponse['intentId'],
         });

     final jsonResponseConfir = jsonDecode(responseConfirm.body);

     ScaffoldMessenger.of(contextsec).showSnackBar(
       const SnackBar(content: Text('Paiement terminé!')),
     );
   } catch (e) {
      
   }
 } ```


Please help me if someone have already solve this problem
````

Comment: It's hard to tell without your full code. Have you tried putting the exact same example as https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/lib/screens/payment_sheet/payment_sheet_screen.dart#L144? Where is your presentPaymentSheet()?